Rewind failed instance of Azure Durable function (isolated)
I migrated my azure durable functions from inProcess to Isolated mode recently. It looks like the "rewind" operation is not supported in isolated mode. Was it replaced? How can I re-execute last step when instance is "failed"?

Please provide your function code.

I use abstractions over functions, so it's not easy to show it (but is the code really needed?). I use durable functions monitor (https://github.com/microsoft/DurableFunctionsMonitor) to review instances and I noticed that I get an error
"Failed to rewind. Rewind is not supported in Isolated mode"

Can you try with this command func durable rewind --id <INSTANCE_ID> --reason <REASON>.

I have followed the MSDOC;
As mentioned in the comments, you can use the command func durable rewind command in function Core Tools to rewind an orchestration instance.
func durable rewind --id <Orchestration_id> --reason "<provide the reason to rewind>"


id: Orchestration ID of the instance.
(required)
reason is optional parameter.


In isolated mode, the IDurableOrchestrationClient was replaced with DurableTaskClient which doesn't support rewind.
https://github.com/Azure/durabletask/issues/731

Updated the answer.

I think the updated answer is missing the first part, am I correct? :) It's still IDurableOrchestrationClient implementation

Try using RewindAsync() in isolated Azure functions. I have tried only with the command given and it worked.

but how can I use RewindAsync() in isolated mode? From what I know, such method doesn't exist

You are right. As per my observation, function core tools is the only available to rewind the isolated azure durable functions.
